# Jquery not removing commas and dollar symbols from number

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC Core project, in the following `View` I'm using jquery to try to remove $ symbol and commas from the SaleAmount input tag before the form is submitted. But it's not doing anything. When I put alert('Test') inside the myJSFunction(), the alert successfully pops up that means the function is called but it's code for removing commas and $ is not working.

**Model**:

```
public class SaleViewModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public float? SaleAmount { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

**Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateSales(List<SaleViewModel> model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ....
}
```

**View**:

```
@model IList<MyProj.Models.SaleViewModel>
....
<form id="target" asp-controller="DbRelated" asp-action="UpdateSales" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData[" ReturnUrl"]" method="post" onsubmit="myJsFunction()">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            ....
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(r => r[i].SaleAmount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "saleAmt" } })</td>
                    ....
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#target").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                myJsFunction();
            });
        });
        function myJsFunction() {
            parseFloat($('.saleAmt').val().replace(/,/g, '').replace(/$/g, ''));
            return false;
        }
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Your replace the values but never reassign that to the updated value to the textbox. But you have cancelled the submit anyway so the form will never post back anything anyway.

Comment: try :  `parseFloat($('.saleAmt').val($('.saleAmt').val().replace(/,/g, '').replace(/$/g, '')));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code does not update the values of your textboxes with the modified text. And in any case, your cancelling the submit so nothing will be posted. You can use

```
$("#target").submit(function () {
    var textboxes = $('.saleAmt');
    $.each(textboxes, function(index, item) {
        var text = $(this).val().replace(/[$,]/g, ''); // remove characters
        $(this).val(text); // update value
    });
});
```

Side note, there is no need to use `parseFloat()`

Comment: Still not working. I noticed that when I replace your code with `$("#target").submit(function () {
            var textboxes = $('.grantAmt').val();
            alert(textboxes);
        });` and enter, say, $15,481 and click on Save button, the alert pops up with $15,481 that means probably `$.each(...)` part is not working.

Comment: Oops - that should be `$.each(textboxes, function(index, item) {` :)

Comment: But that's what you have in your original code. Did you mean something else to change? Another thing I noticed with your code is that only SaleAmount becomes null in the Db but if I change the other input in `@Html.EditorFor(r => r[i].StateName)` along with SaleAmount box, the stateName change reflects correctly in the Db. So, the POST is still working except that SaleAmount is still coming as null.

Comment: I edited the answer after your previous comment :) (it was `$.each(saleAmt, ...`)

Comment: And you cannot possibly be submitting the form with the code in your question (you have cancelled it twice using `event.preventDefault();` and `return false;`) so there is something else you have not told us.

Comment: It's working now (thank you). I'm sorry, I did not realize that you had also made the same Edit in your original response that you informed me about.

Comment: Based on my following observations, I find this solution to be smart: 1. No need to add `onsubmit` attribute in the form tag. 2. No need to use `parseFloat(...)`. 3. No need to call `replace(...)` twice (one for $ and one for commas). 4. No need to call another function from onsubmit attribute of the form tag.

Comment: Despite the answer, what your doing here is bad practice for many reasons and its not recommended. FYI, have a look at [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nX4AEN) - tab into the `Price` textbox, enter a value and tab out.